# Loading content from html jQuery (many different divs)

Tags: jquery, dynamic, load, rel

I have many divs

```
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=19923"></div>
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=98127"></div>
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=39423"></div>
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=32942"></div>
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=15454"></div>
<div id="movies" rel="info.php?m=143436"></div>
```

100+ divs

Can I somehow with jQuery and `.load` update each div to show its relatives files(info.php?m=XXXXX) info?

I found this function in this http://jasonlau.biz/home/jquery/screw-a-jquery-plugin

but i don't want the lazy effect. Just so its start loading from top.

Comment: You do not want to do this. Having your page use 100+ AJAX requests to populate its content is a **very bad idea**. Not only will it cripple your server, it will be a tremendously bad user experience. You *really* need to rethink how you're putting this page together.

Comment: ok thank you. i was worried something like that was the case.

Comment: I agree with @meagar. If you have control over the rendering of the page you should use something akin to server side includes or inline the content of the info.php script into the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is an example of how to do it using jQuery. It finds all elements with the `class` name  `movies` and calls the jQuery `get` function which preforms an ajax request. The response from the request is available as the first parameter of the callback function (`data` in this example). Once you have the data you can use jQuery's `html` function to add it to the DOM element.

```
$(".movies").each(function(){ 
   // make a reference to the current div  
   var element = $(this);
   // get the url
   var url = element.attr('rel');
   // make ajax request
   $.get(url, function(data) {
      // append the data to the div
      element.html(data);
   });
})
```

Keep in mind that HTML ID's should be unique. In your example you had more than one div with the id `movies`. You can select elements by ID using `$('#movies')`, but it will return only the first element that matches the ID. If you have control over the HTML then each div should look more like this:

`<div class="movies" rel="info.php?m=19923"></div>`